# How to issue a bearer token from my identity server using Identity Server 4?

Tags: .net, authentication, identityserver4

I'm working on creating an identity server using the Identity Server 4 framework. I would like an endpoint of the server to take a username and password and issue a bearer token that can then be used by clients.

I've come across the TokenClient object in the IdentityModel.Client namespace but am unsure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html). This is the official documentation. More or less you need this:

```
var client = new TokenClient(
            <IDSTokenEndpoint>,
            <IdsClientId>,
            <IdsClientSecret>);

var userResult = client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("<username>", "<password>").Result;
```

And in the userResult object, you will have the access token.

Before that, of course, you have to configure the client in identity server to support resource owner password, but all of this is described in the documentation, that the link is for.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not the right approach:

https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

If you *really* have to use Resource Owner Password Flow then the answer from m3n7alsnak3 is the correct one.